# Command removing tailwindcss in the input.css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

When I run:
`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

My output.css gets mostly deleted, and only contains a handful of tailwind css, see image:

[image]

I have to run:
`npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css`
to rebuild the file which gets all the tailwind css see:

[image]

But when I run:
`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`
it deletes the output.css again!

I've cleared the NPM cache, re-installed Tailwindcss on a new project and it produces the same issue.

Any help would be welcome, just starting out with backend programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the build command tailwind iterate over your content and check which styles you are use. The other styles are purged. That is a feature of tailwind and makes sure you don't load all the overhead styles you don't use into the CSS file.